# How to pass dropdown value in autocomplete code

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete to a textbox based on dropdown.i have created a WebMethod and then in the view(.aspx)i want to pass the dropdown selected value in request.
 Here is My Code:

```js
function AutoFill() {

  $(".autocomp").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'Tourplan_tourname.aspx/GetCitYByName',
        data: '{ "selectedtext": "' + {
          postcode: $('#ddlTravelType').val()
        } + ',"city": "' + request.term + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.d.length > 0) {
            response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
              return {
                val: item.split('-')[0],
                label: item.split('-')[1]
              };
            }))

          } else {
            response([{
              label: 'No results found.',
              val: -1
            }]);
          }

        }


      });
    },
    select: function(e, i) {
      $("[id$=hdnCitiId]").val(i.item.val);
      if (i.item.val == -1) {
        $(this).val("");
        return false;
      }
    },
    minLength: 1
  }).addClass("fixedHeight");;

}
```

Here is My WebMethod:

```js
[WebMethod] 
public static string[] GetCitYByName(string selectedtext, string city) 
{
  try 
  {
    return BALHotelMaster.GetCitYByName(selectedtext, city);
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is My WebMethod:

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public static string[] GetCitYByName(string selectedtext,string city)
        {
            try
            {
                return BALHotelMaster.GetCitYByName(selectedtext, city);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
           
        }

Comment: My question is How should i pass the 2 paramters in the autofill code??

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:-

> **[source: Multiple types supported](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):**
>
> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats: An array of strings: [
>   "Choice1", "Choice2" ] An array of objects with label and value
>   properties: [ { **label**: "Choice1", **value**: "value1" }, ... ] The label
>   property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be
>   inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just
>   one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you
>   provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
>   label.

So change your `val` property to `value`:-

```js
response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
  return {
    value: item.split('-')[0],
    label: item.split('-')[1]
  };
}))
```

Comment: i Want to pass the dropdown value in the selected text :so how should  i do that?